# Scala - Remove files from folder by file suffix name

Tags: file, scala, directory

I'm looking for an elegant way to remove all files in a folder that have the extension .jpg

I have the following to count the total jpg files in a folder:

```
Option(new File(path).list).map(_.filter(_.endsWith(".jpg")).size).getOrElse(0)
```

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the problem, what does not work?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, the above code counts the total jpg files in a folder, what I'm looking for is a way to delete the files it finds, so remove all jpgs in that folder. Thanks

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the most elegant way to perform filesystem operations with Scala.  See my answer for the nice one-liner to delete files with the .jpg extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for {
  files <- Option(new File(path).listFiles)
  file <- files if file.getName.endsWith(".jpg")
} file.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be getting an error on compile: value endsWith is not a member of java.io.File

Comment: Yep. Sorry, I missed that one.

Comment: instead of the explicit for loop, may be you could just do something like `new File(path).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".jpg")).foreach(_.delete)` ...

Comment: Why are we using `Option` here?

Comment: Option acts as a null check, needed as list and listFiles can return null

Answer (score 0):

Some extra comment, 
To extend @Debilski's answer:
Touching files obviously causes `side effects`. To make this functionally  `effectfull`, please do something like:

```
def deleteFilesBySuffix[G[_]: Sync](suffix: String)(dirName: String): G[Unit] =
    Sync[G].suspend(Sync[G].fromTry(Try(for {
      files <- Option(new File(dirName).listFiles)
      file <- files if file.getName.endsWith(suffix)
    } file.delete())))
```

Then, 
You'll have to run this code with an effect which can delay the 
execution of this method like:

```
import cats.IO
import cats.syntax.foldable._

val r = deleteFilesBySuffix[IO]("jpg")("/tmp")
//Still nothing happened

//Another example with multiple dirs: 
val dirNames = List("/tmp", "/tmp/myDir")
val res = dirNames.traverse_(deleteFilesBySuffix[IO]("jpg"))

//Actually run it.. 
r.unsafeRunSunc()

//Now files are deleted..
```

In my opinion this is much safer, and uses `Scala`'s power of `effects`

Answer (score 0):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) lets you delete all files with a certain extension with a one liner:

```scala
os.list(os.pwd/"pics").filter(_.ext == "jpg").map(os.remove)
```

As described [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/), os-lib is the easiest way to perform filesystem operations with Scala.  It lets you write beautiful, concise, Scala code without dealing with ugliness of the underlying Java libs.

Here's some setup code if you'd like to test this out on your machine:

```scala
os.makeDir(os.pwd/"pics")
os.write(os.pwd/"pics"/"family.jpg", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"pics"/"cousins.txt", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"pics"/"gf.jpg", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"pics"/"friend.gif", "")
```